Writing and reading current weight data from the RS-232 COM port of CAS Scale AD-15 using the Web Serial API
I'm trying to solve the following problem using the Web Serial API: connect a peripheral device - CAS Scale AD-25 via the RS-232 COM port and read weight data. The parameters are as follows:

baudRate: 9600
dataBits: 8
stopBits: 1
parity: none
Transmitted data format is ASCII.

According to the documentation for the scales, the algorithm for obtaining data on the current weight is as follows:
1 First you need to send the command "ENQ" (0x05).
2 If everything is in order, then the response “ACK” (0x06) should be returned.
3 Within 3 seconds you need to send the command "DC1" (0x11).
4 As a result, a response with data should be returned.
My code:
if ("serial" in navigator) {
    console.log("Web Serial API is supported");
}

const filter = { usbVendorId: 01659, usbProductId: 8963 };

const connectButton = document.getElementById("button");

const disconnectButton = document.getElementById("button2");

connectButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({ filters: [filter] });

    await port.open({
        baudRate: 9600,
        dataBits: 8,
        stopBits: 1,
        parity: "none"
    });

    let keepReading = true;
    const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    const data = this.asciiToUint8Array('ENQ'); //tried the same thing const data = new Uint8Array([0x05]);
    await writer.write(data);
    writer.releaseLock();
    console.log(port);

    let reader;

    async function readUntilClosed() {
      while (port.readable && keepReading) {
        reader = port.readable.getReader();
        try {
          while (true) {
            // nothing happened here
            const { value, done } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
              break;
            }
            console.log(value);
          }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        } finally {
          reader.releaseLock();
        }
      }
      await port.close();
    }

    const closedPromise = readUntilClosed();

    disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      keepReading = false;
      reader.cancel();
      await closedPromise;
    });

  } catch (e) {
    // The prompt has been dismissed without selecting a device.
    console.log(e);
  }
});

function asciiToUint8Array(str){
  var chars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i){
    chars.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return new Uint8Array(chars);
};


Thank you for your feedback!
Before writing the script, I checked the functionality of the scales using the CASConnector utility, everything works, the current weight is displayed on the screen.
On the browser page I click the button, and the listener is triggered, which opens a dialog box in which I select the COM port and confirm the connection. There are no errors in the console.
Perhaps I'm writing the COM port incorrectly?
